# Opening different URLs in one Serenity task class?

Tags: serenity-bdd

In Serenity BDD I have a `Task` which opens the login page of an application. I'd like to use this class to not only open the login page but other pages as well.

```
public class StartWith implements Task {

    LoginPage loginPage;

    @Override
    public <T extends Actor> void performAs(T actor) {
        actor.attemptsTo(
                Open.browserOn(loginPage)
        );
    }

    public static Task theLoginPage() {
        return instrumented(StartWith.class);
    }

    // Is this possible???
    public static Task theContactPage() {
        return instrumented(StartWith.class);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to add another static method e.g. `theContactPage` so that my actor could call one of these:

- `StartWith.theLoginPage()`
- `StartWith.theContactPage()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use url as string param.

```
public class StartWith implements Task {
    private final String url;

    public StartWith(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Override
    @Step("{0} start portal at \\{#url\\}")
    public <T extends Actor> void performAs(T actor) {
        actor.attemptsTo(
                Open.url(url)
        );
    }

    public static Task theLoginPage() {
        String url = "http://example.com/login";
        return instrumented(StartWith.class, url);
    }

    public static Task theContactPage() {
        String url = "http://example.com/contact";
        return instrumented(StartWith.class);
    }
}
```